# Connecting to a database from local server

Tags: php, mysql

I operate a large PHP website with some pages connecting to to a MySQL database, which works fine.
I have now created a local test server and have downloaded my PHP pages and my database to wamp server where the pages the don't require a database connection work fine. However, on the pages that use the database, `mysql_connect()` requests throw an error:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I can get a connection working by changing the MySQL request on the PHP page to:

```
$server="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
```

leaving `$database="xxxx";` (original name)

This solution would mean I have to change every page with a MySQL request, and then change them back once development is complete.

Is there a way to get the original MySQL connect requests to work while keeping the original security data on the PHP pages? For example, by changing the wamp server config.inc.php file?

I've tried a number of combinations in the config.inc.php file but none seem to work.

Comment: This webhosting or a VPS?

Comment: You don't keep your database connections in a separate file?

Comment: I know it doesnt help much, but this is why you have a global config file with all of your connection variables stored on it and just `include_once` on every page

Comment: If you have hardcoded the credentials in your code, then the only solution is a massive search and replace, or you can put the same credentials in your WAMP server.

Comment: I'm using WAMP Server for development

Comment: What does your code look like? In legacy mysql_... functions it isn't even possible to use the `$database` parameter on connect! You can't get that error message if you provide an invalid database.

Answer (score 2):

As I sayed in my comment, if you have the mysql connection credentials hardcoded in every file, you only have two alternatives:

1. Replace the credentials in every file (with a massive search and replace)
2. Put the same credentials in your local server. If the code try to connect to a remote host, you can put that host in your host file pointing to your localhost. This way you can simulate the remote environment.

Comment: Hardcoding credentials into source files is a recipe for disaster and should be fixed as soon as possible. The credentials shouldn't be in a path that's even *theoretically* web accessible, or people may be able to grab and download your `inc` files if you're not super careful.

Comment: Thanks guys for the rapid response.Yes the connection data is on every file; What can I say? it seemed a good idea at the time!!!

Answer (score 1):

A good solution would be to save these informations in a file that you include in all your other pages that need a mysql connection.

database.php

```
$server="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$database = "nameofyourdb"

// Might event do the mysql_connect here
```

index.php ou any other page

```
include_once('database.php');
// your code
// containing mysql_query() and so on
```

Then you just need to change informations in one file when yo go from local to production.

Might even use a trick like this to avoid the change:

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1') {
    // local
    $server="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $password="";
    $database = "nameofyourdb";
}
else {
    // production
    $server="localhost";
    $user="...";
    $password="...";
    $database = "...";
}
```

Be careful using the mysql API which is deprecated. You should move to PDO for example.

Comment: your `include` should be `include_once` mysql tends to super stupid things if you dont use `include_once`

Answer (score 0):

As previous answers have stated, you should simply move your connection parameters into a non-human readable file (i.e. outside your webserver root directory, if possible). This way you can store them securely and not risk outside access.

Then, include your file into each page where it is needed. Examples:

config.inc.php:

```
<?php
$db['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$db['user'] = 'user';
$db['pw'] = 'passwd';
$db['name'] = 'dbname';
```

You could even get creative in this file:

```
<?php
// Production settings
$db['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$db['user'] = 'user';
$db['pw'] = 'passwd';
$db['name'] = 'dbname';

// Test/Sandbox settings
/* 
$db['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$db['user'] = 'user';
$db['pw'] = 'passwd';
$db['name'] = 'dbname2';
*/
```

Then simply switch the comments everytime you switch environments.

Then, just include this file into pages where you need to connect to your database:

index.php:

```
<html><head><tltle>My page</title>
...HTML Code here...
<?php include_once("/path/to/config.inc.php"); // Again, store this file outside the web directory, if possible ?>
<?php mysqli_connect($db['host'],$db['user'],$db['pw'],$db['name']); ?>
```